# I don't understand why I don't have access to my package / class?

Tags: java, package, java-package

I have a class called `PointCP2` in a file called `design2` and i have 
`package design;` at the top of my class `PointCP2`. In my test class (`PC2Test`) which is in the same file I have `import design2.*;` at the top, but I keep getting this error whenever I try to run it?

How can I possibly fix this?

```
PointCP2Test.java:5: error: package design2 does not exist
import design2.*;
^
PointCP2Test.java:85: error: cannot access PointCP2
  private static PointCP2 getInput() throws IOException
                 ^
  bad class file: ./PointCP2.class
    class file contains wrong class: design2.PointCP2
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

Comment: I would not have the test class in the same file.  I prefer using JUnit; I'd have separate test classes.  Post your code; can't tell from what you've provided.

Comment: And directory hierarchy, and how you're running it, and from where.